# Magento - New Products in list.phtml template hanging on if(!$_productCollection->count()):

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Magento 1.7.0.2

I am attempting the following code edits:
http://www.dnawebagency.com/displaying-new-products-in-magento-with-pagination

I have been fighting with this on a server I am setting up that is hopefully going live soon and I can't get it to work. I receive the following output:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object in /app/design/frontend/default/cscolors/template/catalog/product/list.phtml on line 35**

Line 35 reads:

```
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
```

I was able to get this to work on a clean install of Magento with a few sample products, but for some reason I can't get it working on the new one even following the same procedure.

I don't really know where to start in debugging this situation and figuring out why it hangs at that line of code, so any advice or ideas of what to look at would be greatly appreciated. There are a couple more code edits on this server, but they SHOULD be far isolated from this problem. The only difference between the two servers essentially is a few Magento Connect add-ons and a couple of extra functions and template code edits included with the current theme.

I have tried using other themes so something is going wrong somewhere with the New.php file, however it is an exact copy of the one I got to work on a new test server, so I'm confused where to go from here. The only two files that should be causing this problem (to my knowledge) are the two files mentioned in the above link, New.php in /app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product, and list.phtml in /app/design/frontend/default/currentthemedir/template/catalog/product. (This is also technically irrelevant to the problem since I get the same error using the default list.phtml file)

Hope I described this adequately, I can provide any more code if needed but as mentioned I copied it directly from the link above.

Here are some of the files in full.

**/app/design/frontend/default/themedir/template/catalog/product/list.phtml:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2009 Irubin Consulting Inc. DBA Varien (http://www.varien.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
 */
?>
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    echo($_productCollection);
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
 ?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="category-products">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml();?>
    <?php // List mode ?>
    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
    <ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <?php // Product Image ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(160,135); ?>" width="160" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" /></a>
            <?php // Product description ?>
            <div class="product-shop">
                <div class="f-fix">
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName())?></a></h2>
                    <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="desc std">
                        <?php echo $_product->getShortDescription() ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="link-more"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() && $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)) : ?>
                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <!--<?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>-->
                    </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>

    <?php else: ?>

    <?php // Grid Mode ?>

    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); 
    ?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        <ul class="products-grid">
        <?php endif ?>
            <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135, 135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" /></a>
                <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></h2>
                <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>

                <div class="actions">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() && $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)) : ?>
                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <!--<?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>-->
                    </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="toolbar-bottom">
        <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/New.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Catalog
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * New products block
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Catalog
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
//Code

class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{
   function get_prod_count()
   {
      //unset any saved limits
      Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->unsLimitPage();
      return (isset($_REQUEST['limit'])) ? intval($_REQUEST['limit']) : 12;
   }// get_prod_count

   function get_cur_page()
   {
      return (isset($_REQUEST['p'])) ? intval($_REQUEST['p']) : 1;
   }// get_cur_page

   /**
    * Retrieve loaded category collection
    *
    * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
   **/
   protected function _getProductCollection()
   {
      $todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

      $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
      $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

      $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
         ->addStoreFilter()
         ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
         ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or'=> array(
            0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
            1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
         ), 'left')
         ->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc')
         ->setPageSize($this->get_prod_count())
         ->setCurPage($this->get_cur_page());

      $this->setProductCollection($collection);

      return $collection;
   }// _getProductCollection
}// Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New
?>
```

**/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Catalog
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */


/**
 * Product list
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Catalog
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Default toolbar block name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_defaultToolbarBlock = 'catalog/product_list_toolbar';

    /**
     * Product Collection
     *
     * @var Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
     */
    protected $_productCollection;

    /**
     * Retrieve loaded category collection
     *
     * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
     */
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
            $layer = $this->getLayer();
            /* @var $layer Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer */
            if ($this->getShowRootCategory()) {
                $this->setCategoryId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
            }

            // if this is a product view page
            if (Mage::registry('product')) {
                // get collection of categories this product is associated with
                $categories = Mage::registry('product')->getCategoryCollection()
                    ->setPage(1, 1)
                    ->load();
                // if the product is associated with any category
                if ($categories->count()) {
                    // show products from this category
                    $this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator()));
                }
            }

            $origCategory = null;
            if ($this->getCategoryId()) {
                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());
                if ($category->getId()) {
                    $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
                    $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
                }
            }
            $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();

            $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

            if ($origCategory) {
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
            }
        }

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }

    /**
     * Get catalog layer model
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer
     */
    public function getLayer()
    {
        $layer = Mage::registry('current_layer');
        if ($layer) {
            return $layer;
        }
        return Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve loaded category collection
     *
     * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
     */
    public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
        return $this->_getProductCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve current view mode
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMode()
    {
        return $this->getChild('toolbar')->getCurrentMode();
    }

    /**
     * Need use as _prepareLayout - but problem in declaring collection from
     * another block (was problem with search result)
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $toolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock();

        // called prepare sortable parameters
        $collection = $this->_getProductCollection();

        // use sortable parameters
        if ($orders = $this->getAvailableOrders()) {
            $toolbar->setAvailableOrders($orders);
        }
        if ($sort = $this->getSortBy()) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
        }
        if ($dir = $this->getDefaultDirection()) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
        }
        if ($modes = $this->getModes()) {
            $toolbar->setModes($modes);
        }

        // set collection to toolbar and apply sort
        $toolbar->setCollection($collection);

        $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
        Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_block_product_list_collection', array(
            'collection' => $this->_getProductCollection()
        ));

        $this->_getProductCollection()->load();

        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Toolbar block
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
     */
    public function getToolbarBlock()
    {
        if ($blockName = $this->getToolbarBlockName()) {
            if ($block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName)) {
                return $block;
            }
        }
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_defaultToolbarBlock, microtime());
        return $block;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve additional blocks html
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAdditionalHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('additional');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve list toolbar HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getToolbarHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
    }

    public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $this->_productCollection = $collection;
        return $this;
    }

    public function addAttribute($code)
    {
        $this->_getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect($code);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPriceBlockTemplate()
    {
        return $this->_getData('price_block_template');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Catalog Config object
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Config
     */
    protected function _getConfig()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config');
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Sort By fields from Category Data
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
     */
    public function prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($category) {
        if (!$this->getAvailableOrders()) {
            $this->setAvailableOrders($category->getAvailableSortByOptions());
        }
        $availableOrders = $this->getAvailableOrders();
        if (!$this->getSortBy()) {
            if ($categorySortBy = $category->getDefaultSortBy()) {
                if (!$availableOrders) {
                    $availableOrders = $this->_getConfig()->getAttributeUsedForSortByArray();
                }
                if (isset($availableOrders[$categorySortBy])) {
                    $this->setSortBy($categorySortBy);
                }
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and it's a stupid one. Thanks for everyone helping me pin down this problem.

After copying the entire production server to mine, file-to-file, the error showed up on my server. I noticed that overwriting it with all the core magento files fixed the problem.

I ran a diff comparison on all folders and didn't find many differences, so I started replacing folders one-by-one to narrow it down. It began working when I reached "/includes/." The difference was the config.php file. It is a small file with only a couple of lines, and the difference was simply an uncommented line that refers to the magento compiler.

I had forgotten that I had enabled and run the compiler on the production server, and editing template files wasn't giving me problems with it like this. Function code, however, is a different story. Re-running the compiler has solved my problem, and the code works as expected now.

Answer (score 2):

Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object in /app/design/frontend/default/cscolors/template/catalog/product/list.phtml on line 35

and your line is count()): ?>

$_productCollection is a non object so you need to check why an instance not created.

Comment: `$_productCollection->count()` is magento methods for retrieving product count on listing page

Comment: @Satish: sorry, that's wrong. The `non-object` error means there is no instance of a class at all, but `$_productCollection === null`.

Comment: Any ideas on anything that might cause the object not to be created? Or at least a method to get me started? I've had friends asking me about IDE's and stuff, but this is just on a hosting account without any tools that I know of. I'm not a developer as you might have been able to tell, just someone good with computers now and then, in way too deep with this project.

Comment: For giving any assistance you need to post your complete list.phtml code and associated Block class.

Comment: Just edited to add the files in question. Additionally, I moved pretty much everything in the file system to a new server to test it, and it seems to be working ok on that test server. Have not migrated the database or anything else, but I'm really puzzled.

Comment: return $this->_productCollection;  in class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List check what is being returned.Is it a class instance or not.

Comment: I found the answer. It was not related to anything in my code. Thank you for your help.